How to produce a string using JavaScript that contains a correctly escaped "&" character for LaTeX tables?
I am trying to write code to generate a LaTeX table using JavaScript. The problem is that I can't find a way to escape ampersand characters in the resulting LaTeX. The result has either been an unescaped ampersand or an ampersand with 2 backslashes. This is part of a website and is on the client side, so it would be preferable not to have to use an NPM package.
I tried using replace and replaceAll. When I use replace like string.replace("&", "\&"), it does not change anything with the string. When I use replace like string.replace("&", "\\&"), it replaces the ampersand with "\&" (a string with 2 backslashes). What I want is for it to replace the ampersand with "&", aka a string with 1 backslash.

Do not try escape characters with replace/replaceAll because there is a lot corner cases. Instead, you should use encodeURIComponent (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). It will replace characters such as &, \ correctly which is already globally tested:


This does not work for LaTeX, as "%" is considered a special character which needs to be escaped anyway.
